# Code to select No button in message box

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to figure out how to use vba code to select the no button in a messagebox. I have a workbook that opens and closes another workbook. When the workbook closes a message box pops up, i.e."Select yes or no". User normally manually will have to click no. Is there a way to do this with code?

This is the first workbook that opens the second workbook with the message box in it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DONEBTN_Click()
Dim WRKBK2 As Workbook
Dim Name As String

Name = "Someones Name"

Set WRKBK2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Second Workbook.xlsm")        

WRKBK2.Sheets(1).Range("H7").Value = Name                 'Name        

WRKBK2.SaveAs Filename:="C:\New File Name For Workbook2.xlsm", _
FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WRKBK2.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is the code located in the second workbook that is under ThisWorkbook Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim MSG1 As String

 MSG1 = MsgBox("Select yes or no?", vbYesNo, "Message Box")

 If MSG1 = vbYes Then

 ' Code does something

 Else

 ThisWorkbook.Save

 ThisWorkbook.Close


 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an event on workbook close that creates this prompt? Why not remove it?  Or are you talking about the save dialog?

Comment: Please clarify what specific message box you would like to select No. It is often helpful to post the code, workbook, or at least a picture of the issue about which you are asking.

Comment: @ Cody G, Cannot remove it because when user later opens the file they should be able to choose the yes or no button based on their situation.

Comment: Sorry everyone still getting used to writing good questions. Please see above example code. Ive tried to be as through as possible, but if anything needs to be clarified please let me know. Thanks for all the input so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the "Save Workbook?" dialog box, use the SaveChanges option of the Workbook.Close method or Application.DisplayAlerts = False. Below example shows both.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbook("Sample Workbook.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False 'Or use .True to save the workbook before closing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the clipboard message, I addopted an stupid way out of it, but it works.

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
```

I added this before close the file.